# How to pass configuration properties to SparkListener?

Tags: java, apache-spark

Stack:

- Java 8
- Spark 2.1.0
- Kafka 0.10.2
- HDP 2.5.2

I am creating a custom SparkListener that will write to Kafka when a Spark job fails at a specific task. In order to do that, I am using the KafkaProducer class which takes in properties. However, we are trying to put this in production, and the Kafka broker addresses cannot be hard-coded into the custom SparkListener class. Thus the need for the use of external properties.

It seems like in the lifecycle of a SparkListener, the onApplicationStart method gets called first (after the constructor). Additionally, I am familiar with passing custom properties to the Spark driver before a Spark Conf/Context gets instantiated via Spark-Submit.

Is there any way to pass external-information to the SparkListener?

```
`public class TestingSparkListener {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        SparkConf sc = new SparkConf().setAppName("Testing Custom Spark Listener");
        sc.set("spark.extraListeners", "my.package.TestSparkListener");
        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sc);
    }
}`

`public class CustomSparkListener {
    static KafkaProducer<String, String> prod;
    @Override
    public void onApplicationStart(SparkListenerApplicationStart applicationStart) {
        SparkConf conf = SparkContext.getOrCreate().getConf(); //problem here
    }
}`
```

Edited to add sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to pass external-information to the SparkListener?

### spark.extraListeners Property

If you use `spark.extraListeners` property, you should define a constructor that accepts a [SparkConf](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkConf):

> Configuration for a Spark application. Used to set various Spark parameters as key-value pairs.

With SparkConf, a pseudo-code could look as follows:

```
val sparkConf: SparkConf = ...
val kafkaConfig = sparkConf.getAllWithPrefix("spark.myapp.kafka")
```

---

See the [relevant code in SparkContext](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2359-L2360) to learn how it looks like under the covers:

```
val constructorTakingSparkConf = constructors.find { c =>
  c.getParameterTypes.sameElements(Array(classOf[SparkConf]))
```

### SparkContext.addSparkListener

If however you want to register a `SparkListener` in your Spark application (in the code), you could use [SparkContext.addSparkListener](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@addSparkListener(listener:org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerInterface):Unit) method instead:

> **addSparkListener(listener: SparkListenerInterface): Unit**
>
> Register a listener to receive up-calls from events that happen during execution.

That gives you a way to initialize your SparkListener as you want. You could create a constructor that would accept additional parameters explicitly.

I don't recommend it however since it hardcodes the SparkListener and there is no way to disable it without recompilation.

Comment: When I try to do this I cannot seem to avoid creating multiple SparkContexts. Is there a way around this?

Comment: It's not possible. There can only be one single instance of `SparkContext` per JVM so...care to share the code to prove I'm mistaken? I'd appreciate.

Comment: Rewrote the answer since I completely missed the point with SparkListeners (looks like "it's been a while since I worked with them" issue). Sorry for confusion.

Comment: I think I've reached a circular dead-end. So I added a constructor to the custom SparkListener that takes one argument, SparkConf. I would try and use Properties, but at runtime it complains that the custom SparkListener does not have a single-argument constructor with SparkConf as the argument.

By adding the SparkConf argument and trying to get the required Kafka properties, Spark now complains that I am trying to create multiple SparkContexts